# jQuery length property: Which element's length will be returned if there are more than one matched elements?

Tags: jquery, size, parent, children, content-length

In the statement

```
var length = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('tr').length;
```

where `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` part gives us a `<tbody>` element, which happens to have *more than one* `tr` children.

**1**. **So which `tr` among those `children` of `tbody` returned by `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` is this particular `tr` whose length is going to be returned by the `.length` property?**

............................................

From the [documentation of the `length` property](https://api.jquery.com/length/),

> Description: The number of elements **in the** jQuery object.

I understand it as: The *'jQuery object'* here is a `tr` element which is a *child* of the `tbody` returned by `$(this).parent().parent().parent()`, and *'the number of elements'* in this jQuery object is the number of `td`s in this `tr`. So the `.length` property here will return the number of `td`s in the `tr` under consideration, right?

**2**. **But in the example given** [here](https://api.jquery.com/length/) (I am copying the code below for reference), the statement

```
var n = $( "div" ).length;
```

assigns `n` the number of `div`s in the `body`. **But shouldn't it rather contain the number of elements in the/direct children of a `div`?**

**1**. And again, which `div`'s `length` will be returned if different `div`s have different lengths?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>length demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: green;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span></span>
  <div></div>
<script>
$( document.body )
  .click(function() {
    $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
    var n = $( "div" ).length;
    $( "span" ).text( "There are " + n + " divs." +
      "Click to add more.");
  })
  // Trigger the click to start
  .trigger( "click" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `length` *does not* find *content length*, it finds *size(number) of objects*. You are complicating it. The `length` property returns the **size** of list of matching elements in the preceding object. That is it! To calculate length/size of children of `div`, `$('div').children().length()` needs to be used.

Comment: @ShaunakD " returns the size of list of matching elements in the preceding object" - thank you for this, I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering jQuery objects `length` does not mean content length inside a particular object.

`length` returns the size/number of matching elements.

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children('tr')  .  length
|_______________________________________________|     |____|
                         |preceding object               |Size of the preceding list
```

So, if `<tbody>` has 4 `<tr>`s - length will return 4.